# "Este" ou "esse" para autorreferência dentro de um livro?

Tags: pronomes

No meio de um livro, ele faz referência a si mesmo para recapitular. O correto seria:

> **Neste** livro, já encontramos exemplos de X e Y.

ou

> **Nesse** livro, já encontramos exemplos de X e Y.

e por quê?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No caso de o livro se referir a si mesmo será **sempre** *neste*. A referida preferência mencionada noutras respostas por *este* para referir algo que acabou de ser mencionado não é aqui relevante. Da mesma forma, alguma informação escrita num objeto referir-se-á sempre a ele com "este" (ex.: "recicle esta embalagem").

Se nos estivéssemos a referir a outro livro, a questão é já mais complexa e depende de fatores contextuais.

Answer (score 0):

Além do *Este* ser utilizado para referenciar algo que acaba de ser mencionado ou será em seguida, como foi supracitado na resposta anterior, o *este* também serve para indicar algo que está próximo de quem fala ou no tempo presente em relação à pessoa que fala, por exemplo:

> **Neste** livro [que carrego comigo], já encontramos exemplos de *X* e *Y*.

Já o *esse* ou *nesse*, também pode ser usado para indicar algo que está longe da pessoa que fala ou no tempo passado em relação à pessoa que fala, por exemplo:

> **Nesse** livro [que tu carregas], já encontramos exemplos de *X* e *Y*.

Ou seja, depende do contexto.

Comment: Depende do contexto, mas só no geral. Neste caso em concreto o livro refere-se a ele próprio, por isso acho que não há lugar ao uso de "nesse".

Comment: @ANeves Exato. Na minha resposta (apesar de não ser específica quanto à pergunta), na minha opinião, se encaixa em "para referenciar algo que acaba de ser mencionado ou será em seguida".

Comment: Entendes que o livro fica mencionado implicitamente? Não tinha pensado nisso assim, mas pode ser uma maneira de ler isto...

Comment: @ANeves Sim, perfeitamente.