# Esse/nesse ou este/neste em um contexto de site?

Tags: pronomes

Eu entendo que este é utilizado quando o objeto está perto de quem fala/algo que irá ser mencionado no dicurso, e esse quando o objeto está longe de quem fala/já foi mencionado no discurso. E no contexto de um site?

Se eu uso no rodapapé do site a seguinte expressão:

"As informações presentes neste site são fornecidas apenas para fins educacionais e de entretenimento."

O correto é neste ou nesse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Este" ou "esse" para autorreferência dentro de um livro?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/este-ou-esse-para-autorrefer%c3%aancia-dentro-de-um-livro)

Answer (score 2):

Eu diria que "este", uma vez que se trata de autorreferência (veja, e.g., essa [questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5193/2764) similar, para livros).

Mas note que "esse" possivelmente também seria aceitável em pt-BR, que, pelo menos informalmente, é [menos rígido](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/559/2764) *nessa* distinção - embora, mesmo em pt-BR, "este" me soe melhor, mais claro.